# Resizing images in a Cloudflare Worker with Denoflare and Wasm Photon

Tags: cloudflare, webassembly, image-resizing, cloudflare-workers, denoflare

I'm trying to learn how to resize images myself in a Cloudflare Worker rather than use [Cloudflare Images](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/cloudflare-images/) or [Cloudflare Image Resizing](https://developers.cloudflare.com/images/image-resizing/) (because of pricing).

There is an [example](https://image-demo.denoflare.dev/) using [Dinoflare](https://denoflare.dev/examples/transform-images-wasm) with WebAssembly from [Photon](https://silvia-odwyer.github.io/photon/), but the example is so large that I can't understand how to use it in simpler way.

Here is the minimal example I would like to create:

- Take a larger image (1+ MB) from Cloudflare R2 (or anywhere) and resize it down to a thumbnail in the worker (preferably using Denoflare + Photon Wasm, but I'm open to other suggestions).

I'm pretty new to JavaScript and TypeScript and very new to Denoflare, so I couldn't even figure out how to import Photon in a simple project. I got the [Hello World example](https://denoflare.dev/guides/serve) working, but that's about all. I do know how to use R2 with regular Cloudflare Workers so the image source is not really an issue, just importing and using Photon in a basic way.

### Update

I'm trying a slightly different approach: directly importing Photon in a Cloudflare project without Denoflare. Hopefully the [ChatGPT ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned) doesn't include help getting to some sort of starting point, but the following is based on the [Photon Node.js docs](https://silvia-odwyer.github.io/photon/guide/using-photon-node/) and ChatGPT help:

```
import photon from "@silvia-odwyer/photon-node";

export default {
  async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
    const imageResponse = await fetch("https://example.com/image.png");
    const imageBuffer = await imageResponse.arrayBuffer();
    const imageBase64 = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(imageBuffer)));
    let phtn_img = photon.PhotonImage.new_from_base64(imageBase64);
    const width = phtn_img.get_width();
    const height = phtn_img.get_height();
    const newWidth = 100;
    const newHeight = Math.floor((newWidth / width) * height);
    photon.resize(phtn_img, newWidth, newHeight);
    let output_base64 = phtn_img.get_base64();
    return new Response(output_base64, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "image/png" },
    });
  },
};
```

Unfortunately, not even the `import` works. I get the following error:

```
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "util"

    node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon-node/photon_rs.js:4:45:
      4 │ const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require(`util`);
        ╵                                              ~~~~~~

  The package "util" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "path"

    node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon-node/photon_rs.js:4273:21:
      4273 │ const path = require('path').join(__dirname, 'photon_rs_bg.wasm');
           ╵                      ~~~~~~

  The package "path" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "fs"

    node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon-node/photon_rs.js:4274:22:
      4274 │ const bytes = require('fs').readFileSync(path);
           ╵                       ~~~~

  The package "fs" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node.
  Add "node_compat = true" to your wrangler.toml file to enable Node.js compatibility.


✘ [ERROR] Build failed with 3 errors:

  node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon-node/photon_rs.js:4:45: ERROR: Could not resolve "util"
  node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon-node/photon_rs.js:4273:21: ERROR: Could not resolve
  "path"
  node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon-node/photon_rs.js:4274:22: ERROR: Could not resolve "fs"
```

I can understand that `fs` and `path` don't work because on a Cloudflare worker I don't have access to the filesystem like I would in Node. Can I get another version of Photon to work in Node?