# How to use Photon image library on Cloudflare Workers

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, webassembly

My end goal is to make a thumbnail image in a Cloudflare Worker.

Previously I asked about [Denoflare with Photon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77109845), but I'm trying to remove as much complexity as possible, so this question is just about Photon. How can I use Photon in a Cloudflare worker? (to do anything at all with Photon, not just resize)

Other people have had the same question (see [Gitter](https://matrix.to/#/!YveKBVCHsdVOFswVCE:gitter.im/$SgEhMbIriKyi8githIH-TwCQbufX58ET7CUSOw87Amo?via=gitter.im&via=matrix.freyachat.eu), [GitHub](https://github.com/silvia-odwyer/photon/issues/46)).

The following sections show the things I've tried.

### Setup

I created a new Cloudflare project:

```bash
npm create cloudflare@latest
```

- name: example-worker
- "Hello World" Worker
- no typescript (use JavaScript)
- compatibility date 2023-05-18
- no deploy (testing locally for now)

### photon npm package

Setup:

```bash
npm install @silvia-odwyer/photon
```

Replace **src/index.js** with:

```js
import * as photon from '@silvia-odwyer/photon';

export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        const imageBytes = new Uint8Array([
            137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 144, 119, 83, 222,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 82, 71, 66, 0, 174, 206, 28, 233, 0, 0, 0,
            4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0, 177, 142, 124, 251, 81, 147, 0, 0,
            0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 14, 196, 0, 0, 14, 196, 1, 149,
            43, 14, 27, 0, 0, 0, 12, 73, 68, 65, 84, 8, 215, 99, 248, 207,
            240, 143, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 226, 33, 60, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130
          ]);
        const photonImage = new photon.PhotonImage(imageBytes, 1, 1);
        const result = photonImage.get_width;
        return new Response(`result: ${result}`);
    },
};
```

Run:

```bash
wrangler dev
```

Error:

```
TypeError: malloc is not a function

example-worker/node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon/photon_rs_bg.js:645:17

function passArray8ToWasm0(arg, malloc) {
    const ptr = malloc(arg.length * 1);  // <- error here
    getUint8Memory0().set(arg, ptr / 1);
    WASM_VECTOR_LEN = arg.length;
    return ptr;
}
```

### photon-node npm package

Setup:

```bash
npm install @silvia-odwyer/photon-node
```

Add `node_compat = true` to **wrangler.toml**:

```ini
name = "example-worker"
main = "src/index.js"
compatibility_date = "2023-05-18"
node_compat = true
```

Replace **src/index.js** with:

```js
import * as photon from '@silvia-odwyer/photon-node';

export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        const imageBytes = new Uint8Array([
            137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10, 0, 0, 0, 13, 73, 72, 68, 82,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 144, 119, 83, 222,
            0, 0, 0, 1, 115, 82, 71, 66, 0, 174, 206, 28, 233, 0, 0, 0,
            4, 103, 65, 77, 65, 0, 0, 177, 142, 124, 251, 81, 147, 0, 0,
            0, 9, 112, 72, 89, 115, 0, 0, 14, 196, 0, 0, 14, 196, 1, 149,
            43, 14, 27, 0, 0, 0, 12, 73, 68, 65, 84, 8, 215, 99, 248, 207,
            240, 143, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 226, 33, 60, 54, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130
          ]);
        const photonImage = new photon.PhotonImage(imageBytes, 1, 1);
        const result = photonImage.get_width;
        return new Response(`result: ${result}`);
    },
};
```

Run:

```bash
wrangler dev
```

Error:

```
⎔ Starting local server...
service core:user:example-worker: Uncaught TypeError: TextEncoder is not a constructor
  at index.js:2964:29 in node_modules/@silvia-odwyer/photon-node/photon_rs.js
  at index.js:11:50 in __require
  at index.js:4148:22
✘ [ERROR] MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

### photon wasm file direct import

Replace **wrangler.toml** with:

```ini
name = "example-worker"
main = "src/index.js"
compatibility_date = "2023-05-18"
```

Copy **photon_rs_bg.wasm** from the **photon** package to the same folder as your **index.js** file (that is, the **src** folder).

Replace **src/index.js** with:

```js
import module from './photon_rs_bg.wasm';

// I'm sure this isn't right but I need some sort of object here.
const importObject = {
    imports: {}
};

const instance = await WebAssembly.instantiate(module, importObject);
    
export default {
    async fetch(request, env, ctx) {
        return new Response('hello');
    },
};
```

Run:

```bash
wrangler dev
```

Error:

```
⎔ Starting local server...
service core:user:example-worker: Uncaught TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="./photon_rs_bg.js" error: module is not an object or function
  at index.js:28:34
✘ [ERROR] MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Looks like the Wasm module might be expecting **photon_rs_bg.js** as the import? But if I provide all those supplementary JS files, then I might as well just import the whole package like I tried to do earlier, right?

### photon-node wasm file direct import

If you do everything the same as the last section but instead copy the wasm file from the photon-node package, you get the following error:

```
⎔ Starting local server...
service core:user:example-worker: Uncaught TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="__wbindgen_placeholder__" error: module is not an object or function
  at index.js:28:34
✘ [ERROR] MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can swap `@silvia-odwyer/photon` with [`@cf-wasm/photon`](https://github.com/fineshopdesign/cf-wasm).

The APIs exposed by the two packages are exactly the same, but `@cf-wasm/photon` is tailored specifically for Cloudflare workers.

Here's an example Cloudflare Worker you could write, which reads an image from an incoming binary stream, writes its size in the server console logs, and returns the image back to the user.

```
import * as photon from '@cf-wasm/photon'

export default {
  fetch(request: Request, env: Env, ctx: ExecutionContext) {
    const imageBuffer = await request.arrayBuffer()
    const imageBytes = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer)

    const photonImage = photon.PhotonImage.new_from_byteslice(imageBytes)
    const width = photonImage.get_width()
    const height = photonImage.get_height()

    console.log(`Received image with size: ${width}x${height}`)

    const headers = request.headers.get('Content-Type') || 'image/jpeg'

    return new Response(imageBuffer, {
       headers: { 'Content-Type': contentType },
    })
  }
}
```

Assuming you're running the Worker locally via `pnpm wrangler dev`, you can test it out by opening another terminal and running:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
  -X PUT "http://localhost:8787/" \
  --data-binary @<YOUR_LOCAL_IMAGE_FILE> \
  --output <COPY_OF_YOUR_LOCAL_IMAGE_FILE>
```